# Display Google Maps API results like a google map textsearch

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my company website i use a Google map API. My problem is that it don't display exactly like on Google maps when i do a text search.
Here are screenshots of what i get from the API and one of the expected result :

[What i have in my Google map api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQXZE.png)

[Now, this is what i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXgG8.png)

So, on the first screen my marker is correct but the icon and company are 'Cap Enfant', a company in the same building.
On the second one, it is exactly what i want to achieve...

I used the Google place api. So, as text search on Google maps gave me the correct result, i tried to use the Textsearch api but i have the same result than with Google place API.
With the textsearch i found my company ( i set a small radius to be sure to found my company only, this ok ), just the icons are not good.

Note : on Google maps when i zoom on the position, Cap Enfant is displayed but not my company ( LTTD Consulting )..

So my question is : Is there a way to display in my api the same way as in Google maps textsearch?

Here is my code :

```
    var map;

function initMap() {

var lttd = new google.maps.LatLng(48.9359628, 2.3051106);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('siegeMap'), {

 zoom: 17
});

  var request = {
    location: lttd,
    radius: 500,
    query: 'Consultant'
  };


  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service.textSearch(request, callback);

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var max_iteration = (results.length < 2) ? results.length : 2;
      var resultCount = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(results[i].geometry.location, lttd) < request.radius) {
          console.log(results[i]);
          var request2 = {
            placeId: results[i].place_id
          };
          service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.getDetails(request2, detailCallback);
          resultCount++;
        }
      }
      map.panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    }
}


function detailCallback(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: 'LTTD Consulting',
        types : ['Consultant'] | ['Consultant informatique'] |['informatique'],
        position: place.geometry.location,
        name:place.name
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot for what you expect looks to be a screenshot of maps.google.com. The places API will not create the UI component that you see in the screenshot. You can, however, create it yourself. You will just need to write the code for it yourself. The upside to this is you can make it look however you want since you are providing the code. You can get all of the information for the place, such as phone number, website, open hours, etc from a place details request. Please see our Place Details document here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

You can use the information supplied by the API to put in a UI component like on maps.google.com.

There are also several other samples that use the Places API that you can look at here. Several of them have custom UI components that you can reference when building your own if you choose to do so:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/#places

I hope this helps!